# How to create a file of constants in Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, enums, constants

Is there a way to create a file of constants in JavaScript, which I can reference and then use?
What I am looking for is something like this:
Constants.js:

var Phones =
      {
        Nokia: 1,
        Samsung: 2
      }

Then, in another JavaScript file JS2.js access those values:
JS2.js:
      alert(Phones.Nokia);

And then, in an aspx file that uses them, reference both of them, like:
    `<asp:ScriptReference Path="../js/JS2.js" />`
    `<asp:ScriptReference Path="../js/Constants.js" />`

Is such an architecture possible? What datatypes can we use? I only exemplified enums because this is what i use right now, but they must be declared in the same file as they are used.

Answer (score 2):

It is very much possible (exactly as you use them). It won't be an enum though, just an object with several numeric fields.

You should use the script reference to constants as the topmost one (logically).

The common types are:

- undefined (variable)
- null (variable)
- String
- Boolean
- Number
- String
- Object

Answer (score 2):

you're doing it right.

make sure the constants are declared first.

JavaScript parses alls scripts and script file links in top down order.