# Auth0 module not found on Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, auth0

I forked the Auth0 repo (for Angular) according to their [github](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/tree/master/01-Login) and I ran npm install on the root folder.
At the end of the process webpack outputs this message: **Cannot find module './auth0-variables'**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4rQs.png)
Did anyone face same issue follow this tutorial and managed to overcome it?

Comment: Why are you cloning the repo and not managing the dependency via npm (adding it to the package.json)?

Comment: You'll need to create auth0-variables when you download the repo from the QuickStarts it auto-fills that information for you.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I am not sure why. I am new programmer and I'm following the steps pointed out by the tutorial.

Comment: @Shrek how should I create these 'auth0-variables' that you mentioned? Can you describe a bit more please?

Comment: Always manage dependencies via npm/package.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file of constants in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152477/how-to-create-a-file-of-constants-in-javascript)

Comment: This is not a dependency. The repo I cloned is a tutorial repo.

Comment: I don't see how my question regarding the Auth0 tutorial would ever be a duplicate of "file of constants" mentioned. Anywayw, I'll come up with the solution this weekend.

Comment: You'll need to create a constants file, an example of that is in the repo.

Comment: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/app/auth/auth0-variables.ts.example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the answers in their readme.md file on the login folder. 
We have to create auth0-variable.ts with your client id and domain

```
https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/tree/master/01-Login
```